# why cannot print non integer epicycloid in command line?

Tags: python, math, geometry, command-prompt

I want to to print epicycloid in command line:

```
import math
import sys
WIDTH=30
R=10.0
N=3.0
DELTA=0.01
pixels=[[0 for y in range(WIDTH)] for x in range(WIDTH)]
for f in range(0,(int)(2*math.pi/DELTA)):
    pixels[(int)(R*math.sin(f*DELTA)-R*math.sin((N+1)*f*DELTA)/(N+1)+WIDTH/2)][(int)(R*math.cos(f*DELTA)-R*math.cos((N+1)*f*DELTA)/(N+1)+WIDTH/2)]=1

for row in pixels:
    for cell in row:
        sys.stdout.write('[]' if cell==1 else '  ')
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

and test with N=3,7,and 3.5, it seems work when N=3 and 7:

N=3

```
                      [][][][][][][][]                  
                    [][]            [][][]              
                  [][]                  [][]            
                  []                      [][]          
          [][][][][]                        []          
      [][]      [][]                        []          
    [][]                                    [][]        
  [][]                                        []        
  []                                        [][]        
[][]                                        []          
[]                                          []          
[]                                      [][]            
[]                                      [][]            
[]                                          []          
[][]                                        []          
  []                                        [][]        
  [][]                                        []        
    [][]                                    [][]        
      [][][]    [][]                        []          
          [][][][][]                        []          
                  []                      [][]          
                  [][]                  [][]            
                    [][]              [][]              
                      [][][][][][][][]
```

N=7

```
                          [][][]                        
                      [][][]  [][][]                    
            [][][][][][]          [][]                  
          [][]      [][]            []                  
        [][]                        [][][]              
        []                          []  [][][]          
        []                                  [][]        
        []                                    []        
    [][][][]                                  []        
    []                                        []        
  [][]                                        []        
  []                                      [][][]        
  []                                      [][]          
  [][]                                        []        
    []                                        []        
      [][][]                                  []        
        []                                    []        
        []                                  [][]        
        []                          []  [][][]          
        [][]                        [][][]              
          [][]      [][]            []                  
            [][][][][][]          [][]                  
                      [][][]  [][][]                    
                          [][][]
```

but when N=3.5 the shape is not I expected (star like something):

```
                    [][][]                              
                [][][]    [][][]                        
            [][]              [][]                      
            []                  [][]                    
          []                      []                    
          []                      [][]                  
        [][]                      [][][][][]            
        [][]                              [][][]        
          []                                  []        
        [][]                                    []      
    [][][]                                      []      
    []                                          [][]    
  [][]                                            []    
  []                                    [][][]          
  []                                        []          
  []                                        [][]        
  []                                          []        
  []                                          []        
  [][]                                        []        
    [][]                                    []          
      [][]            []                    []          
        [][][]    [][][]                  []            
            [][][][]  [][]              [][]            
                        [][][]    [][][]                
                              [][][]
```

I checked the formula so long time,also my parameter used float until convert the result to pixel position,but still not found what is wrong,can anyone help?

(I want to solve it using python,but I found the original java version also has similar problem,I even don't know which type of problem (e.g.:wrong formula,number type casting,or wrong code) causes it)

Comment: I would bet that you are hitting a precision problem especially since the error occurs near [math]\theta = 0[/math]. Look for articles on programming [problems related to floating point math](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a fractional `N=p/q`, you need to go to `2*q*math.pi`.  Let's explore what I mean.

For `N=3.5`,

```
parametric plot (sin(t)-sin(4.5t)/4.5 , cos(t)-cos(4.5t)/4.5) for t in [0,2pi]
```

in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(sin(t)-sin(4.5t)%2F4.5+,+cos(t)-cos(4.5t)%2F4.5)+for+t+in+%5B0,2pi%5D) yields:

[image: N=3.5, 0 to 2pi]

which is similar to your output.

On the other hand, an [upper limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(sin(t)-sin(4.5t)%2F4.5+,+cos(t)-cos(4.5t)%2F4.5)+for+t+in+%5B0,4pi%5D) of [0,4pi] gets the other half:

[image: N=3.5, 0 to 4pi]

Finally, if N is 1/7, we [have to use](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(sin(t)-7sin(8t%2F7)%2F8+,+cos(t)-7cos(8t%2F7)%2F8)+for+t+in+%5B0,14pi%5D) [0,14pi] to get:

[image: N=1/7, 0 to 14pi]